# Add my site logo to google check out page

Tags: php, javascript, out

I want to customise google check out page . Ie , I want to place my logo in google check out page that will appear  when i clicked google check out button in my site this is the place order page  . Is it possible to customize the google check out place order page ?

Comment: Consider editing your title to be more descriptive (e.g. "Add custom logo to Google Check Out page") - it would help draw more people to your question and give it a better chance of being answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the checkout button post to an `<iframe>` element which would load the checkout page inside of a page you create yourself. But, that ends up looking kind of sketchy from a customer's perspective; their browser will give them warnings about encrypted stuff being inside of a non-encrypted page.